# Nestjs exception handling

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm writing a module for nestjs and I want to publish it by npm. the package is a dynamic module for minio.

The problem is that the module work perfectly when it's inside of nest application project but when I copy it to another folder and try to make a npm module out of it, exception handling becomes a problem.

this module contains a `minio.service.ts` file as provider and in this service file there are some conditions that some exceptions like `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` or `PayloadTooLargeException`. when the module is within the nest project exception handling work pretty fine and has no problem but when I try to publish it as npm package all exceptions are thrown as `InternalServerException`.

Here are some of important files:

```js
// src/minio.module.ts

import { Module, DynamicModule, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import {ClientOptions } from 'minio';
import { MinioService } from './minio.service';
import { MinioOptions } from './types/minio.options';
import {MINIO_CONFIG, MINIO_OPTIONS} from "./types/constants";

@Global()
@Module({})
export class MinioModule {
  static register(
    minioConfig: ClientOptions,
    minioOptions: MinioOptions,
  ): DynamicModule {
    return {
      global: true,
      module: MinioModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: MINIO_CONFIG, useValue: minioConfig },
        { provide: MINIO_OPTIONS, useValue: minioOptions },
        MinioService,
      ],
      exports: [MinioService],
    };
  }
}
```

```js
// src/minio.service.ts

import {
  Injectable,
  Logger,
  InternalServerErrorException,
  Inject,
  NotFoundException,
  UnsupportedMediaTypeException,
  PayloadTooLargeException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import { ClientOptions, Client } from 'minio';
import { BufferedFile } from './types/buffered-file.interface';
import { DeleteFileResponse, UploadFileResponse } from './dto/response.dto';
import { IMinioService } from './types/minio-service.interface';
import { MinioOptions } from './types/minio.options';
import { UploadValidator } from './types/upload-validator.interface';
import { MINIO_CONFIG, MINIO_OPTIONS } from "./types/constants";

@Injectable()
export class MinioService implements IMinioService {
  private readonly service;
  constructor(
     @Inject(MINIO_CONFIG) private minioConfig: ClientOptions,
     @Inject(MINIO_OPTIONS) private minioOptions: MinioOptions,
  ) {
    this.service = new Client(this.minioConfig);
  }

  async upload(
    file: BufferedFile,
    bucket: string,
    validator: UploadValidator = null,
  ): Promise<string> {
    if (file.size > 50000) {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    return this.service
      .putObject(bucket, fileName, file.buffer, metaData)
      .then(() => {
        const url = `/${bucket}/${fileName}`;
        return url;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new InternalServerException(err.message);
      });
  }
}
```

if you need to look at the project here is the link to its repository:

https://github.com/nimasfl/nest-minio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `@nestjs/` dependencies `peerDepedencies` and `devDependencies`. This way `typescript` resovles classes is kind of funny, and it becomes an issue when the `instnaceof` check is ran to see if the error is an instance of `HttpException`